# Need to send message to mobile numbers international numbers and also national numbers using php

Tags: javascript, php, smtp, sms, sms-gateway

```
Need help , I want to know and implement this problem.
```

My problem is, In textfield i give greater than or equal to 10 digit mobile number(International Numbers or National Numbers) . when i click submit button need to send some message to that number..

Please give the sample code with brief example using php.

Comment: Please give the sample code you tried

Comment: sad your hopes might shatter. We are here to help each other debugging pieces . If you have to learn try it and then ask here if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: Guys one textfield and submit button that's it. Using PHP Mailer through smtp is there possible to send mail . Just can you please do and post the code and your suggestion Med and Preethi Maurya

Comment: @IRSHADSAHEB You can't send SMS directly from PHP. you need to use an sms gateway. Then you can use their API to send SMS. Some sms gateways support calls via mail. Those SMS gateways are paid services you ll need signup and pay to start sending.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send SMS directly from PHP. You will have to make use of an SMS gateway API. [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com) is a good service.